# Saving GET parameters from an HTACCESS rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My CMS (Expression Engine) requires a few `.htaccess` rules in order to re-write requests that have `index.php` in the url. I recently noticed that this Regex is a little too strong though... and is messing up GET requests like this:

`domain.com/something/?specialurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplesite.com%2Findex.php`

Here, `index.php` is in a GET param, and is causing a redirect loop.

I need a good strategy for allowing my htaccess rules to continue functioning for my CMS, but avoid messing things up when they're part of the query param. My regex is below... any thoughts are appreciated... below are my current .htaccess rules:

```
# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not see much reason to do the URL-normalization with the .htaccess file, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET[^?]+index\.php [NC]
```

The above would work for all `index.php` files anywhere on your site. If you want to redirect for a particular file only, like `/index.php`, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php [NC]
```

Comment: This appears to be working although I'm not entirely sure why; could you describe what the thinking is? Thanks again.

Comment: The second condition works because, well, you're providing the absolute path to your `index.php`. The first one works because it matches all `index.php`s falling left side of `?` i.e. query string separator. Here, `[^?]+` matches all characters but a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

`%{THE_REQUEST}` contains the whole request-line that is next to the method and HTTP protocol version the absolute path of the URI is given - but not normalized.

That means your code right now already fails if `index.php` is URL-encoded as `%69ndex.php` which is totally possible.

Sad news here is that Apache HTTP does not help you with that here. Better check for these conditions inside your PHP script and trigger and appropriate redirect there. I'd also say it's the right place as you should do URL normalization there anyway.

Comment: I really appreciate the context / answer - although I'm not 100% sure how this helps me separate instances of index.php the requested file vs index.php the string in the query param

Comment: You do so by validating the request within your frontend controller (or whatever entry-point you use in your application) and then directly fire a redirect to the correct (canonical) URI in case it wasn't requested by it. It is very easy for the incomming PHP request to differ between inside the path and inside the query param.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [NE (NoEscape) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) in your rules.

Try these rules:

```
# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php/*(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NE]
```

*PS: This flag won't help if you're already getting encoded request from somewhere.*